# spring map entry value as xpath expression

Tags: java, spring

How to give value as xpath expression in spring map .

I am trying like below but is not working.

```
    <bean id="test" class="com.test.testmap">
    <property name="testmap">
      <map>
         <entry key="1" value="/emp/empid"/>
         <entry key="2" value="/emp/empname"/>
       </map>
     </property>
    </bean>
```

Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: Do you want your `test` bean to be a `Map`, or is it really a property of your `com.test.testmap` class?

Comment: Proprty is the map there, yes that is my test class inthatbi defined property as map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spring's `MapFactoryBean` to define the `testmap` property, including the `Map` implementation you wish to use (below is with a TreeMap).

```
 <bean id="test" class="com.test.testmap">
    <property name="testmap">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
            <property name="sourceMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="1">
                        <value>/emp/empid</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry key="2">
                        <value>/emp/empname</value>
                    </entry>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="targetMapClass" value="java.util.TreeMap"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

In your java code, you can use it like this, assuming you have a getter for your testmap field, which you should:

```
com.test.testmap test = (com.test.testmap)applicationContext.getBean("test");
String xpath = (String)test.getTestmap().get("1");
```

You should also stick to Java conventions and rename your class `com.test.TestMap` for readability's sake.